# Executing commands in Chef recipe

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I want to execute following commands through chef-recipe and I need to install the softwares,

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf autogen intltool,  
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool    
sudo apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev  
sudo apt-get install pkg-config    
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

When I tried the following way in my recipe I got an error

```
execute "Build oauth" do  
 command "cd /home/ubuntu/mod_auth_openidc-1.8.0;sudo apt-get install autoconf autogen intltool;sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool"  
end
```

error is

> ec2-52-27-144-189.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com Ran cd
>   /home/ubuntu/mod_auth_o penidc-1.8.0;sudo apt-get install autoconf
>   autogen intltool;sudo apt-get install  build-essential libtool
>   returned 1 ec2-52-27-144-189.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
>   [2015-08-27T11:24:49+00:00] FA TAL:
>   Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited
>   unsuccessfull y (exit code 1)

Please guide me through this

Comment: Why not using the package resource and run chef with sudo chef-client so it can install the packages idempotently ?

Comment: you need to run `apt-get install --force-yes [package] `

Answer (score 1):

Follow @Tensibai advice. Leverage chef's [package resouce](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html)

Don't use "execute" resources difficult to interpret errors (just return code) and not idpotent (meaning you can't run your recipe repeatedly)

```
%w[
autoconf 
autogen 
intltool
build-essential 
libtool    
apache2-threaded-dev  
pkg-config    
libcurl4-gnutls-dev
].each do |dep|
  package dep do
    action :install
  end
end
```

Comment: May worth a word about %w [Here is the shortcuts list](http://caiustheory.com/ruby-shortcuts/)